# Datatable head overshadow select list in html

Tags: html, css, select, datatable, z-index

Hi I'm struggling on React with the correct css properties for each elements (datatable and select).

I've tried with z-index: 1 or z-index:9999 and nothing takes effect.

This is how it looks like

[image]

What should I do?

TIA

Comment: Play with z-index of parent elements as z-indices of child elements are affected by parent's.

Comment: Looks like there is a z-index applied on the table header. Most probably on `<th>`.

Comment: @SanishJoseph Ikr but I even tried to put z-index: 1 !important on it and doesn't work :(

Comment: What if you disable or remove the z-index on <th>? Make sure it’s parent <thread> is also not having the zindex

Comment: Most probably the purpose of that z-index was to give a fixed header while scrolling. So removing the z-index may cause other problems. Make sure it's not breaking anything else.